# iis 7 - cannot find .Net Users configuration tool

Tags: iis-7

I want to find out how I can add some users via the iis 7 .Net users Configuration Tool.
I open up IIS Manager and I have a feature view that has many icons, but not .Net Users.

Surely the .Net Users icon will always be there in the ASP.Net group?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to ensure that IIS7 is configured to allow ASP.NET, and ASP.NET is enabled.

The .NET Users is under the ASP.NET area under the web site, as it sounds like you were expecting.

[image]

Comment: I've got the same issue, and while I see most icons under the ASP.NET header, I don't see .NET Users (and I only see Providers in the Server settings, the icon disappears/is not available per-site).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that handy little '.NET Users' icon is only available for .net 2 sites (according to http://forums.iis.net/t/1169139.aspx).

On that page, CarlosAg suggests temporarily changing your pool to target .net 2, but when I did that, the icon appeared I couldn't open the list of .NET Users because of a providers problem, and the providers configuration area didn't like my .net 4 web.config settings.

I just gave up. Sorry. Not the answer you were hoping for, but it's not available for .net 4.